# One Metricbeat Pod to monitor multiple RabbitMQ containers

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, namespaces, metricbeat

Say I have multiple namespaces on a kube cluster and each namespace has a RMQ container, and these RMQ containers are spread throughout a few nodes, is there a way to deploy **one** metricbeat pod (preferably as a **daemonset**) per node to monitor these RMQ containers? What's the best practice regarding using Metricbeat for monitoring, do you need one metricbeat per container? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metricbeat is installed as a daemonset to ensure that it can get all the node stats across all namespaces. So, you just need one instance of Metricbeat on every node in your k8s cluster

More details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/running-on-kubernetes.html

Comment: I want to get the stats of every RabbitMQ container on each node, can this be accomplished with only one Metricbeat DaemonSet? Since RMQ containers come and go, how can metricbeat dynamically track all the changes?

Comment: It can, because it has access to the docker logs at the node level.